# Python count 2 variable if unique

Tags: python, python-2.7

The code has to count the 2 variable if they are unique.
But i cant get it to work.
Does someone have an idea how i can get it to work?

I want the output to be:

```
C603 100nF 8
```

Here is a litle example of the .txt file.
BaseBoard_V1.2_Componentlist.txt

```
C1                      1nF            C0603                 rcl                                    (24.7 35.9)           R270
C2                      100nF          C0603                 rcl                                    (36.7 32.7)           R180
C3                      10uF_Tantalum  C0603                 rcl                                    (22.7 6.45)           R0
C4                      22uF           C0603                 rcl                                    (25 8.25)             R90
C5                      1uF            C0603                 rcl                                    (22.6 21.85)          R180
```

Code:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import Counter

elements = []

elements.append([])
elements.append([])
elements.append([])

with open('C:\\Python\\Artinis\\BaseBoard_V1.2_Componentslist.txt') as f:
    for i in xrange(10):
        f.next()
    for line in f:
        list = line.split();
        elements[0].append(list[0])
        elements[1].append(list[1])
        elements[2].append(list[2])

for value, package in sorted(zip(elements[1], elements[2])):
    input = value, package
    c = Counter( input )
    print ( c.items() )
```

Output:

```
[('0.22uF', 1), ('C0603', 1)]
[('100', 1), ('R0603', 1)]
[('100', 1), ('R0603', 1)]
[('100', 1), ('R0603', 1)]
[('100', 1), ('R0603', 1)]
[('C0603', 1), ('100nF', 1)]
[('C0603', 1), ('100nF', 1)]
[('C0603', 1), ('100nF', 1)]
[('C0603', 1), ('100nF', 1)]
[('C0603', 1), ('100nF', 1)]
[('C0603', 1), ('100nF', 1)]
[('C0603', 1), ('100nF', 1)]
[('C0603', 1), ('100nF', 1)]
[('10K', 1), ('R0603', 1)]
[('10K', 1), ('R0603', 1)]
[('10k', 1), ('R0603', 1)]
[('10uF_Tantalum', 1), ('C0603', 1)]
[('R0603', 1), ('19.6K', 1)]
[('1nF', 1), ('C0603', 1)]
[('C0603', 1), ('1uF', 1)]
[('2.2uF', 1), ('C0603', 1)]
[('2.2uF', 1), ('C0603', 1)]
[('R0603', 1), ('22K', 1)]
[('R0603', 1), ('22K', 1)]
[('22uF', 1), ('C0603', 1)]
[('R0603', 1), ('483', 1)]
[('53047-05', 2)]
[('ATMEGA32L-8MU', 1), ('QFN50P700X700X100-45N', 1)]
```

I try'd to search on google, i try'd other code but it wont work for me.
Does someone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: How can you say if the variables are unique? can you please give more information, may be an example of what you want to do. Also some lines in the file **BaseBoard_V1.2_Componentslist.txt**

Comment: neither C603 or  100nF are unique according to your output

Comment: @Bharadwaj i've added a few lines of the .txt file.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i see now python doest see them as unique, i have to write litle code for that.

Comment: what makes them unique?

Comment: i think i've asked the question wrong. i want the code to count how manytimes the same 2 variable's are in the file like "100nF C0603" is in there 8 times.

Comment: Ok that is a couple of lines of code

Comment: Can and do you want to help me with that @PadraicCunningham?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to count each element from the second and third elements as  single elements just split, extract the second and third elements with `itertools.islice` and call tuple on the islice object passing it to Counter using a generator expression.:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import islice

with open('test.txt') as f:
    print(Counter(tuple(islice(line.split(), 1, 3)) for line in f))
```

Output from your example:

```
Counter({('10uF_Tantalum', 'C0603'): 1, ('22uF', 'C0603'): 1, ('1nF', 'C0603'): 1, ('100nF', 'C0603'): 1, ('1uF', 'C0603'): 1})
```

If you want a nicer output use str.format and iterate:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    cn = Counter(tuple(islice(line.split(), 1, 3)) for line in f)
    for k, v in cn.items():
        print("{} {} {v}".format(*k, v=v))
```

Output:

```
10uF_Tantalum C0603 1
22uF C0603 1
1nF C0603 1
100nF C0603 1
1uF C0603
```

Comment: @DjordyWinckler, made it simpler

Comment: is it possible to get a cleaner output?

Comment: @DjordyWinckler, cleaner in what sense?

Comment: you mean ele 1 ele2 count ?

Comment: put a /n (newline) after every output. ('10uF_Tantalum', 'C0603'): 1, (newline) ('22uF', 'C0603'): 1, etc.

Comment: You have a dict so you cannot do that but you can iterate over and print

Comment: can you help me again?

Answer (score -1):

Provided that we have data already organized in this way:

```
elements = [
    ("a", "b"),
    ("c", "d"),
    ("a", "b"),
    ("c", "d"),
    ("a", "b"),
]
```

We can create a set of unique elements:

```
elset = set(elements)
```

And then display how many times each unique element is present in the original list:

```
for e in elset:
    print e[0], e[1], elements.count(e)
```